# Leave Request - Supervisor Comments

Tags: workflow, comments

I have a working leave request workflow currently.   Workflow is started once user submits information on list, if approved, email is sent to supervisor and requester. It is also automatically added on 2 calendars. One for Staff that can view how is off and for how long, and the other for Admin Only that can view more detail such as leave type or employee comments.

The only thing I cannot get to work is the supervisor's comments.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to get the supervisor's comments from the field to the email to work.  Here are the screenshots of the workflow.  The email comes back with that section blank.

Please Help.

Thanks

[image: Workflow Screen]

[image: Current Item - Supervisor Comments]

Comment: Try changing the return type to "Plain Text". It appears as though your Supervisor Comment field is a multi-line text field. It's possible that your email program is stripping out any formatting or HTML, even when none is actively used in the multi-line text box. I was able to get both "As String" and "Plain Text" to work on my end, but I am also using HTML-enabled reading in Outlook. Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. I tried what you said but it didn't work...

Comment: Your screenshots appear correct. One thing I just noticed is that the Font Size in your Define Email Message screenshot appears to be set to size 3. That is very, very small. Is it possible that the comments are being added, but formatted to Font Size 3?

Answer (score 0):

What is the order of the workflow? Is it initiated "when a item is created"?

Is it possible that the email is being generated by the workflow BEFORE the supervisor adds their comments?

What I'm thinking is that you might need two workflows - one for initial creation > send email to supervisor for approval, and one after the supervisor has added their comments > send confirmation to employee. The second workflow could have a condition set where the workflow waits until Supervisor comments are not blank.

Hope that helps.